# Why two if statements that are logically similar showing different outputs,below are two if statements which got me confused

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

Here the `pattern` is a string and `arr` is an array of strings, and `map` here is a hashmap i.e `HashMap<Character,String> map = new HashMap<>();`

```
if (!map.get(pattern.charAt(i)).equals(arr[i]) {
    return false;
}
```

The above one is working.
But what is wrong with the next one?

```
if (map.get(pattern.charAt(i))!=(arr[i])){
    return false;
}
```

This is a part of my solution for question no. 290 leetcode. When I use first if statement the whole code is working, but for the second version of if statement not all test cases are getting passed. Why so?

```
class Solution {
    public boolean wordPattern(String pattern, String s) {
        String[] arr=s.split(" ");
        if (arr.length!=pattern.length()) {
            return false;
        }
        HashMap<Character,String> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(pattern.charAt(i))){
                //**this line is my doubt**//
                if (!map.get(pattern.charAt(i)).equals(arr[i])){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    if (map.containsValue(arr[i])) {
                        return false;
                }
                 map.put(pattern.charAt(i),arr[i]);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use Java, so I'm wondering what does `map.get(pattern.charAt(i))` return? I'd guess `.equals()` is there for a reason.

Comment: In java `equals` method is used to check if two `String` are equal characters by character but using `==` or `!=` means it's checking whether two variables point to the same memory location. Hope this helps. Also, this is a duplicate of this question please check here. [String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/string-equals-versus)

Comment: thank you so much for clearing my doubt!!